# Convert sqlx.DB to sql.DB in Go

Tags: sql, go

What's the best way to convert the type `sqlx.DB` (jmoiron/sqlx)  to `sql.DB` (database/sql)?

I'm currently using the package `github.com/golang-migrate/migrate` and it requires an existing connection to follow `sql.DB` interface.

```golang
func Migrate(db *sqlx.DB) error {
    driver, err := postgres.WithInstance(db, &postgres.Config{})
    m, err := migrate.NewWithDatabaseInstance(
        "file://src/db/migrations",
        "postgres", driver)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return m.Up()
}
```

Update:
I mixed the description and added more details. The title was correct.

Answer (score 9):

You can convert an `sql.DB` (which is a struct, not an interface) to an `sqlx.DB` using sqlx's `NewDb` method: [Code](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/master/sqlx.go#L253-L257)

This method requires your `*sql.DB` as well as the driver name as a string.

Here's an example using "mysql" for the driver:

```
var myDb *sql.DB

...

anSqlxDb := sqlx.NewDb(myDb, "mysql") // returns *sqlx.DB
```

Edit: to add the answer to the new question which was asked in the comments, it is also possible to do the reverse and get an `*sql.DB` from an `*sqlx.DB`.

The `*sqlx.DB` struct contains an embedded `*sql.DB` ([Code](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/master/sqlx.go#L246-L251)). As an embedded struct, it can be retrieved using its type name (`DB`):

```
var mySqlxDb *sqlx.DB

...

var anSqlDb := mySqlxDb.DB
```

Comment: How would you convert from sql to sqlx?

Comment: Convert what, specifically? The above code is how an instance of `sql.Db` can be converted to an instance of `sqlx.DB`.

Comment: Convert the opposite, from `sqlx.DB` to `sql.Db`

Comment: Let me add that to my answer (although it is a different question).

Answer (score 5):

In [doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB)

> sqlx.DB is a wrapper around sql.DB which keeps track of the driverName
>   upon Open, used mostly to automatically bind named queries using the
>   right bindvars.

So you can do like

```
db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=foo dbname=bar sslmode=disable")
sqlDB := db.DB // sqlDB is *sql.DB
```